# How to display a stack trace when an exception is thrown

Tags: c++, exception, stack-trace

I want to have a way to report the stack trace to the user if an exception is thrown. What is the best way to do this?

I'd like it to be portable if possible. I want information to pop up, so the user can copy the stack trace and email it to me if an error comes up.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It depends which platform.

On GCC it's pretty trivial, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes) for more details.

On MSVC then you can use the [StackWalker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) library that handles all of the underlying API calls needed for Windows.

You'll have to figure out the best way to integrate this functionality into your app, but the amount of code you need to write should be minimal.

Comment: the post you link to mostly points to generating a trace from a segfault, but the asker specifically mentions exceptions, which are quite a different beast.

Comment: I agree with @Shep - this answer does not really help with getting a stack trace of the throwing code on GCC. See my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The link points to an answer specific to `Linux` not `gcc`.

Comment: You can override the throw mechanism of `libstdc++` (used by GCC and potentially Clang) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11674810/651937).

Answer (score 98):

[Andrew Grant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/691742/913098) does ***not*** help getting a stack trace of the *throwing* function, at least not with GCC, because a throw statement does not save the current stack trace on its own, and the catch handler won't have access to the stack trace at that point any more.

The only way - using GCC - to solve this is to make sure to generate a stack trace at the point of the throw instruction, and save that with the exception object.

This method requires, of course, that every code that throws an exception uses that particular Exception class.

*Update 11 July 2017*: For some helpful code, take a look at [cahit beyaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42664648/913098), which points to http://stacktrace.sourceforge.net - I haven't used it yet but it looks promising.

*Update 29 July 2023*: Stack trace libraries as of July 2023:

- [C++23 `<stacktrace>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace): C++23 will introduce `<stacktrace>`, which some standard library implementations already [support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23#C.2B.2B23_library_features) or partially support.
- [boost stacktrace](https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/): Reference implementation for `<stacktrace>` proposed by the authors. It is feature-full but requires various [configuration and dependencies](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html).
- [backward-cpp](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp): A widely used library and provides a lot of information, including code snippets for each frame. Depending on your system it has various [configuration and dependencies](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp#user-content-configuration--dependencies). It supports most platforms other than mingw.
- [cpptrace](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/cpptrace): A newer C++ stack trace library that is simple, portable, and self-contained.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead. Could you provide some other?

Comment: And archive.org doesn't know it, either. Damn. Well, the procedure should be clear: throw a custom class' object that records the stack trace at the time of the throw.

Comment: On the home page of StackTrace, I see `throw stack_runtime_error`. Am I correct in deducing that this lib only works for exceptions derived from that class, and not for `std::exception` or exceptions from third-party libraries?

Comment: So sadly the answer is "No, you cannot get a stack trace from a C++ exception", the only option is to throw your own class which generates a stack trace when it's constructed. If you're stuck using things like, say, any part of the C++ std:: library, you're out of luck. Sorry, sucks to be you.

Comment: @CodeAbominator is it still the case that we simply cannot get stack trace of std:: exceptions? I tried cpptrace. It require us to use its own exception classes and does not catch std:: exceptions. Is boost stacktrace and backward-cpp or any other library capable of catching std:: exceptions?

Comment: @MsA Yes. There is no way to inject stack traces into std exceptions. But, with cpptrace you can catch both cpptrace exceptions and std exceptions, or just std exceptions because cpptrace exceptions are std exceptions. There's also a wrap macro that can be used to catch std exceptions and re-throw as cpptrace exceptions.

Answer (score 71):

If you are using Boost 1.65 or higher, you can use [boost::stacktrace](https://boost.org/libs/stacktrace):

```
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

// ... somewhere inside the bar(int) function that is called recursively:
std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
```

Comment: The [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html#stacktrace.getting_started.handle_terminates_aborts_and_seg) explain not only capturing a stack trace, but how to do it for exceptions and asserts.  Great stuff.

Comment: Does this stacktrace() prints source file and line numbers as given in the GettingStarted guide ?

Comment: Coming soon to C++23 - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace

Answer (score 29):

I would like to add a **standard library option** (i.e. cross-platform) how to generate exception backtraces, which has become available with **C++11**:

### Use [`std::nested_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception) and [`std::throw_with_nested`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested)

This won't give you a stack unwind, but in my opinion the next best thing.
It is described on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37227893/4069571) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/348862/4069571), how you can **get a backtrace on your exceptions** inside your code without need for a debugger or cumbersome logging, by simply writing a proper exception handler which will rethrow nested exceptions.

Since you can do this with any derived exception class, you can add a lot of information to such a backtrace!
You may also take a look at my [MWE on GitHub](https://github.com/GPMueller/mwe-cpp-exception), where a backtrace would look something like this:

```
Library API: Exception caught in function 'api_function'
Backtrace:
~/Git/mwe-cpp-exception/src/detail/Library.cpp:17 : library_function failed
~/Git/mwe-cpp-exception/src/detail/Library.cpp:13 : could not open file "nonexistent.txt"
```

Comment: This is probably a lot better, if you're willing to do the extra work, than the usual dumb stack trace.

Comment: It's been a while since I've felt horrified of how C++ can butcher such a simple concept. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 22):

Unix:  [backtrace](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html)

Mac:  [backtrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/backtrace.3.html)

Windows: [CaptureBackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This doesn't help you display a stack trace when exceptions are *thrown*.

Comment: On Windows, you could use [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4223401/) for that. Note [that function will appear not to work when called from a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22493385/)

Answer (score 10):

If you are using C++ and don't want/can't use Boost, you can print backtrace with demangled names using the following code [[link to the original site]](https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/).

Note, this solution is specific to Linux. It uses GNU's libc functions backtrace()/backtrace_symbols() (from execinfo.h) to get the backtraces and then uses __cxa_demangle() (from cxxabi.h) for demangling the backtrace symbol names.

```
// stacktrace.h (c) 2008, Timo Bingmann from http://idlebox.net/
// published under the WTFPL v2.0

#ifndef _STACKTRACE_H_
#define _STACKTRACE_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <cxxabi.h>

/** Print a demangled stack backtrace of the caller function to FILE* out. */
static inline void print_stacktrace(FILE *out = stderr, unsigned int max_frames = 63)
{
    fprintf(out, "stack trace:\n");

    // storage array for stack trace address data
    void* addrlist[max_frames+1];

    // retrieve current stack addresses
    int addrlen = backtrace(addrlist, sizeof(addrlist) / sizeof(void*));

    if (addrlen == 0) {
    fprintf(out, "  <empty, possibly corrupt>\n");
    return;
    }

    // resolve addresses into strings containing "filename(function+address)",
    // this array must be free()-ed
    char** symbollist = backtrace_symbols(addrlist, addrlen);

    // allocate string which will be filled with the demangled function name
    size_t funcnamesize = 256;
    char* funcname = (char*)malloc(funcnamesize);

    // iterate over the returned symbol lines. skip the first, it is the
    // address of this function.
    for (int i = 1; i < addrlen; i++)
    {
    char *begin_name = 0, *begin_offset = 0, *end_offset = 0;

    // find parentheses and +address offset surrounding the mangled name:
    // ./module(function+0x15c) [0x8048a6d]
    for (char *p = symbollist[i]; *p; ++p)
    {
        if (*p == '(')
        begin_name = p;
        else if (*p == '+')
        begin_offset = p;
        else if (*p == ')' && begin_offset) {
        end_offset = p;
        break;
        }
    }

    if (begin_name && begin_offset && end_offset
        && begin_name < begin_offset)
    {
        *begin_name++ = '\0';
        *begin_offset++ = '\0';
        *end_offset = '\0';

        // mangled name is now in [begin_name, begin_offset) and caller
        // offset in [begin_offset, end_offset). now apply
        // __cxa_demangle():

        int status;
        char* ret = abi::__cxa_demangle(begin_name,
                        funcname, &funcnamesize, &status);
        if (status == 0) {
        funcname = ret; // use possibly realloc()-ed string
        fprintf(out, "  %s : %s+%s\n",
            symbollist[i], funcname, begin_offset);
        }
        else {
        // demangling failed. Output function name as a C function with
        // no arguments.
        fprintf(out, "  %s : %s()+%s\n",
            symbollist[i], begin_name, begin_offset);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // couldn't parse the line? print the whole line.
        fprintf(out, "  %s\n", symbollist[i]);
    }
    }

    free(funcname);
    free(symbollist);
}

#endif // _STACKTRACE_H_
```

HTH!

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK libunwind is quite portable and so far I haven't found anything easier to use.

Comment: libunwind 1.1 doesn't build on os x.

Answer (score 6):

Since the stack is already unwound when entering the catch block, the solution in my case was to **not catch certain exceptions** which then lead to a SIGABRT. In the signal handler for SIGABRT I then fork() and execl() either gdb (in debug builds) or Google breakpads stackwalk (in release builds). Also I try to only use signal handler safe functions.

GDB:

```
static const char BACKTRACE_START[] = "<2>--- backtrace of entire stack ---\n";
static const char BACKTRACE_STOP[] = "<2>--- backtrace finished ---\n";

static char *ltrim(char *s)
{
    while (' ' == *s) {
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}

void Backtracer::print()
{
    int child_pid = ::fork();
    if (child_pid == 0) {
        // redirect stdout to stderr
        ::dup2(2, 1);

        // create buffer for parent pid (2+16+1 spaces to allow up to a 64 bit hex parent pid)
        char pid_buf[32];
        const char* stem = "                   ";
        const char* s = stem;
        char* d = &pid_buf[0];
        while (static_cast<bool>(*s))
        {
            *d++ = *s++;
        }
        *d-- = '\0';
        char* hexppid = d;

        // write parent pid to buffer and prefix with 0x
        int ppid = getppid();
        while (ppid != 0) {
            *hexppid = ((ppid & 0xF) + '0');
            if(*hexppid > '9') {
                *hexppid += 'a' - '0' - 10;
            }
            --hexppid;
            ppid >>= 4;
        }
        *hexppid-- = 'x';
        *hexppid = '0';

        // invoke GDB
        char name_buf[512];
        name_buf[::readlink("/proc/self/exe", &name_buf[0], 511)] = 0;
        ssize_t r = ::write(STDERR_FILENO, &BACKTRACE_START[0], sizeof(BACKTRACE_START));
        (void)r;
        ::execl("/usr/bin/gdb",
                "/usr/bin/gdb", "--batch", "-n", "-ex", "thread apply all bt full", "-ex", "quit",
                &name_buf[0], ltrim(&pid_buf[0]), nullptr);
        ::exit(1); // if GDB failed to start
    } else if (child_pid == -1) {
        ::exit(1); // if forking failed
    } else {
        // make it work for non root users
        if (0 != getuid()) {
            ::prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, PR_SET_PTRACER_ANY, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        ::waitpid(child_pid, nullptr, 0);
        ssize_t r = ::write(STDERR_FILENO, &BACKTRACE_STOP[0], sizeof(BACKTRACE_STOP));
        (void)r;
    }
}
```

minidump_stackwalk:

```
static bool dumpCallback(const google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor& descriptor, void* context, bool succeeded)
{
    int child_pid = ::fork();
    if (child_pid == 0) {
        ::dup2(open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY), 2); // ignore verbose output on stderr
        ssize_t r = ::write(STDOUT_FILENO, &MINIDUMP_STACKWALK_START[0], sizeof(MINIDUMP_STACKWALK_START));
        (void)r;
        ::execl("/usr/bin/minidump_stackwalk", "/usr/bin/minidump_stackwalk", descriptor.path(), "/usr/share/breakpad-syms", nullptr);
        ::exit(1); // if minidump_stackwalk failed to start
    } else if (child_pid == -1) {
        ::exit(1); // if forking failed
    } else {
        ::waitpid(child_pid, nullptr, 0);
        ssize_t r = ::write(STDOUT_FILENO, &MINIDUMP_STACKWALK_STOP[0], sizeof(MINIDUMP_STACKWALK_STOP));
        (void)r;
    }
    ::remove(descriptor.path()); // this is not signal safe anymore but should still work
    return succeeded;
}
```

Edit: To make it work for breakpad I also had to add this:

```
std::set_terminate([]()
{
    ssize_t r = ::write(STDERR_FILENO, EXCEPTION, sizeof(EXCEPTION));
    (void)r;
    google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler::WriteMinidump(std::string("/tmp"), dumpCallback, NULL);
    exit(1); // avoid creating a second dump by not calling std::abort
});
```

Source: [How to get a stack trace for C++ using gcc with line number information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636456/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-c-using-gcc-with-line-number-information) and [Is it possible to attach gdb to a crashed process (a.k.a "just-in-time" debugging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509088/is-it-possible-to-attach-gdb-to-a-crashed-process-a-k-a-just-in-time-debuggin)

Answer (score 5):

I recommend http://stacktrace.sourceforge.net/ project. It support Windows, Mac OS and also Linux

Comment: On its home page, I see `throw stack_runtime_error`. Am I correct in deducing that this lib only works for exceptions derived from that class, and not for `std::exception` or exceptions from third-party libraries?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, check out [BugTrap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14618/Catch-All-Bugs-with-BugTrap). Its not longer at the original link, but its still available on CodeProject.

Answer (score 3):

on linux with g++ check out this lib

https://github.com/camelspotter/libinstrument

it does all the work for you

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem, and though I like portability, I only need gcc support.  In gcc, execinfo.h and the [backtrace](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) calls are available.  To demangle the function names, Mr. Bingmann has [a nice piece of code.](https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/) To dump a backtrace on an exception, I create an exception that prints the backtrace in the constructor.  If I were expecting this to work with an exception thrown in a library, it might require rebuilding/linking so that the backtracing exception is used.

```
/******************************************
#Makefile with flags for printing backtrace with function names
# compile with symbols for backtrace
CXXFLAGS=-g
# add symbols to dynamic symbol table for backtrace
LDFLAGS=-rdynamic
turducken: turducken.cc
******************************************/

#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include "stacktrace.h" /* https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/ */

// simple exception that prints backtrace when constructed
class btoverflow_error: public std::overflow_error
{
    public:
    btoverflow_error( const std::string& arg ) :
        std::overflow_error( arg )
    {
        print_stacktrace();
    };
};


void chicken(void)
{
    throw btoverflow_error( "too big" );
}

void duck(void)
{
    chicken();
}

void turkey(void)
{
    duck();
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        turkey();
    }
    catch( btoverflow_error e)
    {
        printf( "caught exception: %s\n", e.what() );
    }
}
```

Compiling and running this with gcc 4.8.4 yields a backtrace with nicely unmangled C++ function names:

```
stack trace:
 ./turducken : btoverflow_error::btoverflow_error(std::string const&)+0x43
 ./turducken : chicken()+0x48
 ./turducken : duck()+0x9
 ./turducken : turkey()+0x9
 ./turducken : main()+0x15
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : __libc_start_main()+0xf5
 ./turducken() [0x401629]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Poppy](https://github.com/orling/Poppy) can gather not only the stack trace, but also parameter values, local variables, etc. - everything leading to the crash.

Comment: "Then sprinkle the STACK~ macros over your code... Just place it at the start of each function you want stack-traced." Uh yeah, no.

Answer (score 2):

The following code stops the execution right after an exception is thrown. You need to set a windows_exception_handler along with a termination handler.  I tested this in MinGW 32bits.

```
void beforeCrash(void);

static const bool SET_TERMINATE = std::set_terminate(beforeCrash);

void beforeCrash() {
    __asm("int3");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(windows_exception_handler);
...
}
```

Check the following code for the windows_exception_handler function:
http://www.codedisqus.com/0ziVPgVPUk/exception-handling-and-stacktrace-under-windows-mingwgcc.html

Answer (score 1):

Cpp-tool [ex_diag](https://code.google.com/p/exception-diagnostic/) - easyweight, multiplatform, minimal resource using, simple and flexible at trace.

Comment: I checked this project at 2017.12.24,  source and download both not accessiable.

Comment: I just checked https://code.google.com/archive/p/exception-diagnostic/source/default/source and the source is downloadable. Can you try one more time?

Comment: Documentation link dead.

Comment: Just checked and both links above opens. Could you describe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A working example for OSX (tested right now on Catalina 10.15). Not portable to linux/windows obviously. Probably it will be usefull to somebody.

In the "Mew-exception" string you can use backtrace and/or backtrace_symbols functions

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern "C" void __cxa_throw(void *thrown_object, std::type_info *tinfo, void (*dest)(void *));
static void (*__cxa_throw_orig)(void *thrown_object, std::type_info *tinfo, void (*dest)(void *));
extern "C" void luna_cxa_throw(void *thrown_object, std::type_info *tinfo, void (*dest)(void *))
{
    printf("Mew-exception you can catch your backtrace here!");
    __cxa_throw_orig(thrown_object, tinfo, dest);
}


//__attribute__ ((used))
//__attribute__ ((section ("__DATA,__interpose")))
static struct replace_pair_t {
    void *replacement, *replacee;
} replace_pair = { (void*)luna_cxa_throw, (void*)__cxa_throw };

extern "C" const struct mach_header __dso_handle;
extern "C" void dyld_dynamic_interpose(const struct mach_header*,
                               const replace_pair_t replacements[],
                               size_t count);

int fn()
{
    int a = 10; ++a;
    throw std::runtime_error("Mew!");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    __cxa_throw_orig = (void (*)(void *thrown_object, std::type_info *tinfo, void (*dest)(void *)))dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "__cxa_throw");

    dyld_dynamic_interpose(&__dso_handle, &replace_pair, 1);

    fn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Update: the dyld_dynamic_interpose API this code sample depends on is a [no-op](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/dyld/blob/ce1cc2088ef390df1c48a1648075bbd51c5bbc6a/libdyld/libdyldGlue.cpp#L476-L480) as of dyld-940 / macOS 12