# Log the call stack on a crash

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ display stack trace on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691719/c-display-stack-trace-on-exception)

How to log a crash exception with the call stack? Is it possible? Can any brief example be given, or at least set to the right direction of how to?

Comment: which OS do you want this on?

Comment: windows, thanks for commenting it!

Answer (score 1):

The [StackWalker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack) library can help in printing the call stacks for windows. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691719/c-display-stack-trace-on-exception) SO answer has more details