# How to implement printstacktrace using C++ like Java

Tags: c++, printstacktrace

Is there any methods to implement a 'printstacktrace' method in C++ like the Java do?

Comment: the code would be platform dependent and also you need to check the abi used by your program, say, if there is frame pointer saved on stack, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ display stack trace on exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691719/c-display-stack-trace-on-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backtrace() or StackWalker for Unix or Windows.

See this previous SO question:

> [C++ display stack trace on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691719/c-display-stack-trace-on-exception)