# boost::exception - how to print details?

Tags: c++, boost

I have such codein my program:

```
catch (boost::exception& ex) {
    // error handling
}
```

How can I print details? Error message, stacktrace etc.?

Comment: Well, judging from the documentation, `boost::exception`, which is meant to be a base class, doesn't seem to have any actual exception information. Did you have a look at `boost::get_error_info`? I have no idea if that'll help. You could also check out `boost::diagnostic_information`. I only used the `std::exception`s so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something as generic as a `boost::exception`, I think you are looking for the [`boost::diagnostic_information`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/exception/doc/diagnostic_information.html) function to get a niceish string representation.

```cpp
#include <boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp>

catch (const boost::exception& ex) {
    // error handling
    std::string info = boost::diagnostic_information(ex);
    log_exception(info); // some logging function you have
}
```

To get the stack for an exception, I'd start with the StackOverflow question [C++ display stack trace on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691719/c-display-stack-trace-on-exception).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [boost::diagnostic_information()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/exception/doc/diagnostic_information.html) to get the actual error messages and origin of the exception.
i.e.

```
catch (const boost::exception& ex) {
    // error handling
    std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(ex);
}
```