# Async safe writing functions for Signal handler on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, signals

I'm trying to write a Signal handler that gets everytime called when my programm crashes and than writes the informations the `boost::stacktracer` api gives me into a file on my harddrive.
Writing the handler is no problem as well as crashing my programm isn't.
But now I am totally unsure what functions I *can* use in my handler.
The functions I'm going to use needs to be Async safe I get that but I just can't find a list for windows which functions are *allowed* to use I got a list for [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) which is pretty clear and pretty easy to understand but useless since the most functions are from `<unistd.h>` and this does not exist in windows or atleast not in VS2017s compiler.
Since I read that `<io.h>` is pretty simillar to `<unistd.h>` I tried to achiev my goal with functions out of this header.

So I use `_sopen_s(&fileHandle,"E:\\UslessStuff\\stacktracer.txt",_O_RDWR,_SH_DENYNO,_S_IWRITE);`

to open a file and

```
  if(_write(fileHandle,&boost::stacktrace::stacktrace(),boost::stacktrace::stacktrace().size())==-1) {
switch(errno) {
  case EBADF:
    perror("Bad File Discription");
    break;
  case ENOSPC:
    perror("No Space left on Device");
    break;
  case EINVAL:
    perror("Invalid Parameter: Buffer was NULL");
    break;
   default:
     perror("Unexpectet Error");


    break;
    }
  }
```

for writing.
So I want to no is it *okay* to use this functions?
Also how far can I go with strings in a Signal?
As you see I try to get informations from `boost::stacktrace::stacktrace()` which gives me a perfect result when I use it with `cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace()` but writes me just 2 RAM addresses in my Textfile when I try to write it like shown above so I think I migth need to *extract* the string from `boost::stacktrace::stacktrace()` with creating a  `boost::stacktrace::frame fr` which would result in `fr.source_file().c_str();` so it'd give me a `std::string` back which I probably would need to pack in a `char*` which really sounds like I shouldn't do it in a Signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little authoritative information on this in general, even on POSIX. Instead, I'd suggest posting to a queue/signaling a condition from inside the async handler (using safe primitives) and doing the rest elsewhere.

TTBOMK this abstraction is already present and ready-to-use in Boost:

- Boost Asio [`signal_set`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html)

Also, for your particular purpose it does appear that Boost Stacktrace has helper functions that are expressly async-safe: [Handling terminates, aborts and Segmentation Faults](http://boostorg.github.io/stacktrace/stacktrace/getting_started.html#stacktrace.getting_started.handle_terminates_aborts_and_seg):

```
#include <signal.h>     // ::signal, ::raise
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void my_signal_handler(int signum) {
    ::signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to("./backtrace.dump");
    ::raise(SIGABRT);
}
```

Comment: First thank you (again) I gonna have a look at `signal_set`.
Yeah I know that boost contains ` boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to("")` I worked myself througth the tutorial the problem is that `safe_dump_to()` is deactivated and shouldn't be used on windows since it crashes.

*Async safe dumping into files on Windows OS was causing hangs on some platforms and now is disabled #33. Users are encouraged to update to the latest Boost release.* 

From the 1.67.0 Patchnotes.
I would be damn Happy if this would just work haha :D

Comment: @alovaros I'd look at the `signal_set` then. Perhaps you can just use condition variable instead, depending on your program. Also, perhaps you can compare with some ... more "mature" (read: old) libraries that might fit your requirements... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691719/c-display-stack-trace-on-exception I can't say I have much experience there, so: good luck!

Comment: Okay thank you very much again :) I'll hopefully will finish this project soon. Gonna read me through the alternatives (lol even c++11 hase such functionallity....)