# How to debug code that seg faults at load time?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I have a fairly complex C++ code that generates a segmentation fault as soon as it loads.  The first statement in main() never gets executed.  I think the problem lies in a static library libWhatever.a because the segmentation fault only occurs if I try to instantiate an object from that library.  How would a smart person debug this problem?

EDIT #1: The code that instantiates the object never executes.  In fact I put it inside an if-statement with a clause that I know is impossible (but the compiler does not know).  That is why I think the code is seg-faulting at load-time.

Comment: `if I try to instantiate an object` You should be able to set a breakpoint on that and catch it in the debugger, even if it happens before `main`, presumably during construction of some global object.

Comment: If you're not sure where the erroring code is, it sounds like you may need to learn how to [display a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/691719/2602718) when your code breaks.

Comment: Do you have global variables that depend on each other? Maybe you have a case of static initialization order fiasco

Comment: show us minimum requirements

Comment: I don't know if I'm a smart person but I would type `gdb <executable>`, then the `R`un command, and wait until gdb interrupts the segfault and then see what's up.

Comment: Excellent advice.  I will try all those things (unless I solve it).

Comment: If no statement in `main()` is executed then it is some constructor of a global variable. So the next thing is to identify which global variable. Then understand why it is failing (probably because something is not initialized correctly).