# Disabled  __LINE__ macro?

Tags: c++, macros

I want to do some exception handling. I plan on using the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macros.

I have some header Vectors.hpp in which I implement some class for a vector structure. In this class I implement the `operator []` and I want to throw an exception each time this operator is used with an out of bounds index. I test this class in some source test.cpp. I want then to be able to see the exact line in test.cpp where this happened.

However I know that the `__LINE__` macro is disabled every time you include some header, so what I got is the line in Vectors.hpp where I handle the exception and not the line in test.cpp. Is there a nice way to get around this? Or, how would one implement his own `__LINE__` macro?

Comment: Maybe this one is similar to you question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026649/getting-information-about-where-c-exceptions-are-thrown-inside-of-catch-block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__LINE__` macro is never disabled. It is expanded where you write it. There are two ways to write code (more precisely, there are two ways to produce tokens):

- write it manually
- use the preprocessor to write code

If you have it is some file `foo.cpp` like this (just exemplary, that's very bad code actually)

```
class Foo {
public:
    Frob operator[] (size_t) { throw __LINE__ }
};
```

then `__LINE__` is always 3 and `__FILE__` is always `foo.cpp`.

That's because the macros are expanded where they are used. The solution would be to find a way to get them expanded where *you want* it, and the only way to do so is to define another macro:

```
#define safe_subscript(foo, index) \
      try {foo[index];} \
      catch(...) { std::cout << __LINE__ << '\n'; }

....
safe_subscript(foo, 256);
```

But as you see, this leads to quite ugly code and workarounds.

Real Solution: Just throw an exception upon out of bounds (`throw std::out_of_range`), or do it like [the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at):

```
T& operator[] (size_type i) { return store_[i]; }
T& at (size_type i) { if (i>size_) throw std::out_of_range("crap");
                      return store_[i]; }

T operator[] (size_type i) const { return store_[i]; }
T at (size_type i) const { if (i>size_) throw std::out_of_range("crap");
                           return store_[i]; }
```

If your user receives an exception, he is ought to debug where *he/she/it* made a programming error.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the current line as part of the exception. Define your exception as

```
struct MyException : public std::exception {
    MyException(const char* line) : errorLine(line);
    const char* errorLine;
};
```

And use it as follows:

```
if (isError())
     throw MyException(__LINE__);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you have to add that information when you catch the exception, very usually we create an class extending std::exception with some additional attributes for mounting a clear error message, on which you include the `__LINE__` , `__FILE__` or even `__FUNCTION__`

This one also answers that:
[Getting information about where c++ exceptions are thrown inside of catch block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026649/getting-information-about-where-c-exceptions-are-thrown-inside-of-catch-block)