# cpp exception get the details of throw caller

Tags: c++, exception

I have some custom exception like below

```
class myexception: public exception
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "My exception happened";
  }
} myex;

void testException(){
 throw myex;
}

void doSomething2(){
   testException();
}
void doSomething1(){
   doSomething2();
}


int main () {
  try
  {
    doSomething1();
  }
  catch (exception& e)
  {
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

so in the main function I can not know the caller of a throw(which function has thrown exception), how to get that details ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call-stack for exceptions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222890/call-stack-for-exceptions-in-c)

Comment: GCC specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-program-crashes

Comment: Why not write a meaningful message for exception, which includes name of throwing function? With C++11 you can use `__func__` to get the name of current function.

Comment: For debugging purpose you can set a breakpoint and look at the call stack. If you want in release also, maybe rethrow the exception like here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/rethrow_exception/.  Dependent on you compiler, you could also use \__FUNCTION__ or \__FILE__ and \__LINE__ to throw in the `return`

Comment: In C++11 and later, there is a predefined macro `__func__` that can be used to obtain the name of the function in which it is called as a nul-terminated string (but not a string literal), and that can be passed to the constructor of your exception and a copy stored.  Any answer for pre-C++11 compilers - if there is one - will be compiler specific, so you will need to specify your compiler.

Comment: This link  //https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/ is also fine but, caller function name is not printed only address is printed

Answer (score 1):

There are no easy *portable* ways to do this in `C++` that I am aware of. There are some reasonably complicated ways to get  full stack trace using Operating System specific calls.

The simplest way I use to get the source of the exception is using MACROS.

Macros are not recommended where they can be avoided but this is one of the few places they prove useful.

I tend to uses something slightly more complicated than this but this is the basics of it:

```
#ifndef NDBUG
#define throw_runtime_error(msg) \
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string(msg) \
        + " line: " + std::to_string(__LINE__) \
        + " file: " + std::string(__FILE__))
#else
#define throw_runtime_error(msg) throw std::runtime_error(msg)
#endif

void doSomething2(){
    throw_runtime_error("My runtime error.");
}
void doSomething1(){
   doSomething2();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        doSomething1();
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You don't get a full trace but you do get to see where the exception was thrown. The MACRO only includes the debugging information when `NDBUG` is not set because *release* builds should set that macro to disable debugging information.

Answer (score 1):

this should be helpful:

[How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-program-crashes)

you can find out way to print call stack and print that in exception handler.

Comment: Hi, when I run the example given in this function names are not printed, below is my output , 
/test/Example/Debug/backstrace[0x400749]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36cb0)[0x7f1388167cb0]
/test/Example/Debug/backstrace[0x4007a2]
/test/Example/Debug/backstrace[0x4007ca]
/test/Example/Debug/backstrace[0x4007d5]
/test/Example/Debug/backstrace[0x400804]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f1388152f45]
/test/Example/Debug/backstrace[0x400669]

Comment: This link https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/ is also fine but, caller function name is not printed