# Error: "Control may reach end of non-void function" in c++

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

I understand the basics of the error message; it is alerting me that this code may not return anything at all. However, I do not understand why. My code is perfect, is it not?

```
rational operator / (const rational &lhs, const rational &rhs)
{
if(rhs.numerator() != 0)
{
    int numerator = lhs.numerator() * rhs.denominator();
    int denominator = lhs.denominator() * rhs.numerator();
    rational quotient(numerator, denominator);
    return quotient;
}
else cout << "error" << endl;
}   //this is where error is occurring
```

Comment: "Control reaches the end of a non-void function [*without* returning a value on all execution paths]"

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement. _"My code is perfect, is it not?"_ Way off ...

Answer (score 1):

Correction made with inscribed comments.

```
rational operator / (const rational &lhs, const rational &rhs)
{
  if(rhs.denominator() != 0) {
    int numerator = lhs.numerator() * rhs.denominator() + 
                    rhs.numerator() * lhs.denominator();
    int denominator = lhs.denominator() * rhs.denominator();
    rational quotient(numerator, denominator);
    return quotient;
  }
  else {
   // what should be returned?
   // let's return lhs, as caller is expecting something, lhs is better than nothing
   // ideally should raise exception, and program shopuld not continue further
   cout << "error" << endl; 
   return lhs; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on raising an exception? Is this something that I have to code in?

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480640/how-to-throw-a-c-exception

Answer (score 0):

So its pretty simple right, your function needs to return a type `rational`. In the case that this fails:

```
if(rhs.numerator() != 0)
```

then you will not return anything of that type. Hence the warning.

Comment: So I can't return any kind of error message? What if there is no type rational that suits the situation?

Comment: @MattC. Then you should consider throwing an exception instead.

Comment: @MattC.: You defined your function to return a `rational`, so it has to return a `rational` -- or throw an exception. Or you can change the return type so it can always return a sensible value.