# What is benfit of throw catch over if else

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480640/how-to-throw-a-c-exception) and I know about standard exception [objects](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/2-3.html). My question is, What is the benefit of using exception over simple function calling ?

For Example Code A

```
#include <stdexcept>

int compare( int a, int b ) {
    if ( a < 0 || b < 0 ) 
        throw std::invalid_argument( "received negative value" );
    else
        // return normal results
}

try {
    compare( -1, 3 );
}
catch( const std::invalid_argument& e ) {
    // do stuff with exception... 
}
```

and Code B

```
int compare( int a, int b ) {
    if ( a < 0 || b < 0 ) 
        throwFunc( "received negative value" );
    else {
        // Perform normal task
     }
}


compare( -1, 3 );

throwFunc(const std::string& e ) {
    // do stuff with exception... 
}
```

What is the benefit of Code A over Code B ? and benefit of standard exception objects ? Ultimately we just throw a variable or string.

Comment: With exceptions, the call-stack will be properly unwound and constructed objects properly destructed. And with exception objects it's easier to categorize different kinds of exceptions (like e.g. `std::invalid_argument` versus `std::logic_error` etc.).

Comment: In code B, what would you return in `compare`, what would you do after (erroneous) `compare` call ?

Comment: I feel like in order to answer this, we need to know what `throwFunc` actually does. If it accesses some global singleton or something the answer may be different ...

Comment: C++ Core Guidelines [E.3: Use exceptions for error handling only](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#e3-use-exceptions-for-error-handling-only)

Comment: typically you catch the exception that someone else was throwing at you or vice versa, that is something you cannot get from using `if-else` at least not in a clean way

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate, or at least not the duplicate of that particular question. This question is not about return codes vs exceptions at all.

Comment: For me the question is "What is the benefit of using exception over simple function calling ?". The duplicate seems a good match to me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you think that processing the exception means only some work with the exception object itself. This is indeed true if, for example, all you want to do with the exception is to log it and then terminate the program. In this case your approach with `throwFunc` can work as well.

But the main thing about exceptions is that you need to catch them exactly in the right place up the call stack, process then and continue executing your program. The `compare` function often does not have enough information on what to do with the error, so, when you throw the exception, the stack is being unwind and the program execution jumps to the nearest `catch`, which should be exactly the place where you can process the error.

With your `trowFunc` you have no way to jump *up* the stack to find such a place. You can call the functon, do something there, but then you return to your `compare` function, which still does not know what to do with the problem. And its caller may as well not know what to do there. And so on.

Answer (score -2):

**`if/else` conditional statements have nothing to do with `throw` or `try/catch` blocks that safely handles exceptions.**

**try/catch:**

You can `throw` an exception if you expect your code block/section of having any possible error/undefined/exceptional cases. Without interrupting your program control flow by abrupt errors and aborts, you safely execute your exception-possible code segment inside `try` block, raise an exception by `throw` if you already know about the characteristic of the  exception that you are expecting, and then execute a `catch` block corresponding to exception by handling that exception. This way your program doesn't change its control flow by making abrupt jumps.

[image]

Whenever there is an exception, program control flow changes because the process will call an indirect procedure related to the exception, through a jump table called exception table, to the operating system subroutine called exception handler.

When the exception handler finishes processing, one of three things happens,depending on the type of event that caused the exception:

1.The handler returns control to the current instruction Icurr, the instructionthat was executing when the event occurred.

2.The handler returns control to Inext, the instruction that would have executednext had the exception not occurred.

3.The handler aborts the interrupted program.

**if/else**:

`if/else` are conditional statements. `if` checks for a condition to execute a code segment. `else` can extend `if` by executing a code segment in case `if` condition is false.

**Solution Specific To Your Example:**

```
int compare( int a, int b ) { 
if ( a < 0 || b < 0 )
 throwFunc( "received negative value" ); else {
 // Perform normal task
 } 

} 
compare( -1, 3 ); 

throwFunc(const std::string& e ) { 
// do stuff with exception... 
}
```

There is no guarantee that `compare (-1,3);` will execute or anything after confronting an unsafely handled code section would execute.