# Queue Implementation Template return type function in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, queue

I am trying to implement **Queue Data Structure using Linked List** in C++, where I've made use of classes in both the Linked List and Queue. One thing which I am not getting is that for example, I've written a method `front()` which will return the top element or the first element of the queue. However, I'm confused about what should I return and how should I return in the case of templated class when my queue is **empty**. If it would've been `int` type queue, I would've simply returned `-1`. Here I'm confused what should I return if my `queue()` is already empty and how should I return from a **templated class**.

Here's the code I've written

```cpp
// Implementation of Queue Data Structure using List
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T data;
    Node<T>*next;
};
template<typename S>
class Queue
{
public:
    Node<S>*q = NULL;
    void enqueue(S data){
        Node<S>* newNode = new Node<S>;
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if(q!=NULL){
            Node<S>* temp = q;
            while(temp->next!=NULL){    
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = newNode;
        }
        else{
            q = newNode;
        }
    }
    void print(){ //Utility method for printing the queue with ease
        Node<S>*temp = q;
        while(temp){
            cout<<temp->data<<endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    auto dequeue() -> decltype(q->data){
        Node<S>*temp = q;
        q = q->next;
        S value = temp->data;
        delete temp;
        return value;
    }
    auto front() -> decltype(q->data){
        return q->data;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Queue<int>q;
    q.enqueue(1);
    q.enqueue(2);
    q.enqueue(3);

    cout<<"Front is "<<q.front()<<endl;

    cout<<"Before dequeue() printing\n";

    q.print(); 

    cout<<"Dequeue operation() "<<q.dequeue()<<endl;

    cout<<"After deueue() printing\n";

    q.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about throwing exception if the queue is empty? Or use `std::shared_ptr` to share the value with `front`. If it is empty, simply return `nullptr`.

Comment: You might [`throw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) or document the function as *"Calling `front` on an empty container is undefined."* (as [`std::vector::front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) does) or return a [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Can you suggest?

Comment: If I remember well, in the standard library, for std::queue, they throw an exception when the queue is empty. Maybe this is the most elegant way.

Not sure how to do what? throw? or shared_ptr?

Comment: @RaphSchim um, you can suggest both?

Comment: If I throw an error will I be getting any warning (not returning anything)? @Maverobot

Comment: @RaghavSharma [How to throw a C++ exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480640/how-to-throw-a-c-exception). You might need good [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) of C++.

Comment: I know how to throw an exception, what I wanted to ask is would I have to write any return statement after throwing an exception?

Comment: @Maverobot I'm getting this `warning` 
 **warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }` If I'm throwing an exception**.

Here's the code
`auto front() -> decltype(q->data){
  try{
   if(!q){
    throw "The queue is empty\n";
   }
   return q->data;
  }
  catch(const char* msg){
   cout<<msg<<endl;
  }
 }`

Comment: @RaghavSharma You should not catch your own exception. It is supposed to be caught by the user of the class. `auto front() -> decltype(q->data) {
  if (!q) {
    throw std::runtime_error("The queue is empty");
  }
  return q->data;
}
`